# How get the click event of a ListBoxItem whilst using ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, listbox

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListBoxItem.IsSelected)">

                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="Blue"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="75" />

    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dtTeamInGame">
        <WrapPanel  >
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPath" Text="{Binding Path = Number, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="35" ></TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPath2" Text="{Binding Path = KnownName, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="125"  ></TextBox>

        </WrapPanel>

    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox  x:Name="listBox" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource dtTeamInGame}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="29,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="381">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHome" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,108,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

I have a Listbox which contains Textboxes in the item and I would like for when I click the textbox the item the textbox is in should be selected. Before adding:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownHome" />
        </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

the list box item would be selected if I clicked the textbox within an item. If I remove the container style above it works as intended but I need the container style because I would like to carry out some tasks if the user clicks an item that is already selected.

Comment: Does it help if you base your ItemContainerStyle on the default ListBoxItem style?  `<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">`

Comment: Yes!, Cheers.  @EdPlunkett That works as expected if you post as an answer I can mark it. 

Cheers,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to keep behavior from the default `ListBoxItem` style, but you also want to add your own stuff to it. That's easy: Use the `BasedOn` property of the style to inherit from the existing default style.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style 
        TargetType="ListBoxItem" 
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"
        >
        <!-- Your stuff -->
```